# Backbone.marionette compositeview ignores the index for addItemView

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am using Backbone.Marionette's CompositeView and I want to insert a new model at index 0 of the collection and have it appear as the first view in the composite.

I have this code to insert the element:

```
PlansApp.Plans.collection.unshift new PlansApp.Plan data
```

The problem is that the CompositeView ignores the index of the newly inserted item in the collection.

in Backbone.Marionette, the appendHtml method looks like this:

```
  appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView, index){
    collectionView.$el.append(itemView.el);
  },
```

The index argument is never used.

The newly inserted view will always be placed at the end of the composite.

How can I get it to appear at position 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design, due to the number of edge cases that have been identified in supporting sorted collections directly.

The `index` parameter was added so that developers could individually add support in their applications. There's a wiki page that shows an example of how to do this: https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/wiki/Adding-support-for-sorted-collections

```
MySortedView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  // ...,

  appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView, index){
    var childrenContainer = $(collectionView.childrenContainer || collectionView.el);
    var children = childrenContainer.children();
    if (children.size() === index) {
      childrenContainer.append(itemView.el);
    } else {
      childrenContainer.children().eq(index).before(itemView.el);
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: The wiki page is actually located here: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Adding-support-for-sorted-collections

Answer (score 0):

The original Derick's answer is a bit dated for the current version of Marionette, and the wiki contains only an example for a collectionview.

Here's what I use for compositeviews currently:

```
appendHtml: (collectionView, itemView, index) ->
  $container = @getItemViewContainer(collectionView)
  if index is 0
    $container.prepend itemView.el
  else
    childAtIndex = $container.children().eq(index)
    if childAtIndex.length
      childAtIndex.before itemView.el
    else
      $container.append itemView.el
```